# What master combines application development and modeling and simulation engineering?

Tags: masters

I am engineer in  process and chemical engineering but now I am working for a small company where I am research and development engineer (most of the tasks I work on is developping applications and now it was said I am going to work on modeling and simulation)
I would like to know what kind of master can I do in order to have a diploma covering application development and modeling and simulation?

Comment: Welcome to academia.SE and thanks for your question! Our scope here is pretty narrowly defined (perhaps too narrowly defined) - we don't accept "shopping" questions, and we're not experts in your field. You might consider editing your question to be more broad, e.g., "how should I search for an appropriate master's program?"

Comment: We specifically exclude "shopping questions" because they tend not to be "portable"—in the sense that they wouldn't help anyone except the original poster.

Comment: In this case, however, I don't think there are a lot of programs that combine both—the skill sets are very divergent. But you might want to get a better sense of what you're working on before you try to plunge into a master's—especially since the length of such a program may be more than your bosses are willing to wait for the project.